# searching using enter key on windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c# , i have one `TextBox` and one `gridview` when user type something in `Textbox` to search, the `gridview` is filled succesfully when clicked on search button.
But my concern is instaed of search button use ENTER KEY TO search data in gridview.

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e1, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (e1.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) 
    { 
       string sql = "[DocEntry],[JobCardNo],[ITEMNAME],[OD] ,[PlanQty],
                      [FinalInspectionRemarks] ,[OrderDate] ,[Division]
                          WHERE JobCardNo ='" + textBox3.Text.ToString() + "'";  
       SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, objConn1); DataSet ds = new DataSet(); 
       objConn1.Open(); 
       da.Fill(ds, "ProductionInventoryReport"); 
       dataGridView1.DataSource = ds; //dataGridView1.DataBind();  
       dataGridView1.DataMember = "ProductionInventoryReport"; 
       objConn1.Close(); e1.Handled = true; 
     } 
 }
```

I have tried this but not working

Comment: Do you mean you want pressing Enter to have the same effect as clicking the Search button? Or do you want to remove the Search button from the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of TextChanged event do it on [KeyPress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx) event.

First attach the event to the textbox, either in designer or in code like:

```
textBox3.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.textBox3_KeyPress);
```

Then

```
 private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // enter key pressed
            { 
             //searchMethod(); 
            }
        }
```

Its better if you extract the search code to a separate method and then call the same method against your search button and KeyPress event.

Comment: @user187068, yes do that in the form constructor, or you can attach the event in the designer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**AcceptButton**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Property.
  Try the below code in your **Constructor** or **Form_Load** Event.

```
this.AcceptButton =  //give your search Button name here
```

If you want to *remove Search Button* then you can go with the below code: (Rough code)

```
Button btnSearch = new Button();  //Create a New Button
btnSearch.Visible = false;         //Optional
btnSearch.Click += new EventHandler(/*Your Method name for Search*/);
this.AcceptButton = btnSearch;
```

Comment: he is talking about `enter key` in `textbox` not `button`

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ eventhough it should work?

Comment: Setting the `AcceptButton` means that pressing Enter will have the same effect as pressing the button itself.

Comment: @Mr_Green Now, it is _not_ wrong. I meant to say you answer is correct, despite Some1.Kill.The.Dj's comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textBox3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {

    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        //Your searchMethod();
    }
}
```